# ng2-slim-loading-bar for HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to use use ng2-slim-loading-bar to show my progress when getting request from the back end.

Here is my component.

```
ngOnInit(){
        this._slimLoader.start();
        this._productsAdminService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => {
                products.forEach(function(product){
                    if(product.cat_id === 1) product.catName = 'Dota Shirts';
                    if(product.cat_id === 2) product.catName = 'Gym Shirts';
                    if(product.cat_id === 3) product.catName = 'Car Shirts';
                });
                this.products = products;
                console.log(this.products);
                this._slimLoader.complete();
            },
            err => console.log(err));
    }
```

This request should take 3-5 seconds from request to resolve so I need to make the progress bar to load like that. The problem here is that when I load the page, nothing will show until the callback is done. After showing all my products it will instantly show then gone.

Anything wrong in here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in the past.  When you use `this._slimLoader.start();` it starts loading the bar from 0% and it increments slowly.  This means you can't visually see it starting since it's at the edge of the browser.

Instead of using `.start()`, you can set the progress to a certain percentage e.g. `this._slimLoader.progress = 70;` and then call `.complete();` once the request has completed.

I believe YouTube uses this style.

Answer (score 0):

As todo's answer mentions, the bar starts at 0 %. You need to set it to 20 % and call `start()`. However, `start()` just increments in some interval, and when it hits 100 %, the bar just disappears, wrongly indicating that the loading has finished. It would be nice if `start()` accepted a callback called on each step so you could stop it at 90 %. But it does not.

So here is what I did in our project (Red Hat Automated Migration Toolkit):

- In our HTTP service wrapper (handling OAuth), we fire an event,
- which is then caught by our `LoadingIndicatorService`.
- `LoadingIndicatorService`

  - wraps the `SlimLoaderBarService`,
  - and keeps track of how many HTTP requests there are in progress.
  - Then it counts the percent and puts it to a scale of 20 to 90 %.
  - When all HTTP requests are done, it stays at 90 % for about a second, and then `complete()` is called.

If you have multiple requests for each navigation step, this looks quite naturally and provides a good UX.
If you typically only have 1 request, then you might want to either adjust the CSS based animation (make it longer) or use `start()` afterall.

Here are some key code parts:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingIndicatorService {

    constructor(
        private _slimBarService: SlimLoadingBarService,
        private _eventBusService: EventBusService,
    ) {
        // Register the LoadingSomething event listeners.
        this._eventBusService.onEvent
            .filter(event => event.isTypeOf(LoadingSomethingStartedEvent))
            .subscribe((event: LoadingSomethingStartedEvent) => this.loadingStarted() )
        this._eventBusService.onEvent
            .filter(event => event.isTypeOf(LoadingSomethingFinishedEvent))
            .subscribe((event: LoadingSomethingFinishedEvent) => this.loadingFinished() )
    }

    public getSlimService(){
        return this._slimBarService;
    }


    private counter: number = 0;
    private max: number = void 0;

    private reset() {
        this.counter = 0;
        this.max = void 0;
    }

    public loadingStarted(){
        this.counter++;
        this.max = this.counter;
        this.updateProgress();
    }

    public loadingFinished(){
        this.counter--;
        this.updateProgress();
    }

    private updateProgress() {
        if (this.counter == 0) {
            this._slimBarService.height = "2px";
            this._slimBarService.visible = true;
            this._slimBarService.progress = 95;
            this.max = void 0;
            Observable.timer(700).subscribe(() => {
                this._slimBarService.complete();
            });
        }
        else {
            // max - counter = finished.
            // If the things to load are added after something loaded, the progress would go back.
            // But let's rely on that loading will start fast at the beginning.
            // Start at 20, jump to 90.
            let percent = 20 + 70 * (1 - (this.max - this.counter) / this.max);
            this._slimBarService.height = "3px";
            this._slimBarService.color = "#39a5dc";
            this._slimBarService.visible = true;
            this._slimBarService.progress = percent;
        }
    }

}


    let responseObservable2 = responseObservable.do(
        () => console.log("Request SUCCEEDED"),
        () => console.log("Request FAILED"),
        () => {
            console.log("Request FINISHED");
            if (this._eventBus) {
                console.log("Request FINISHED, firing");
                this._eventBus.fireEvent(new LoadingSomethingFinishedEvent(responseObservable))
            }
        }
    );
```

HTTP service wrapper:

```
@Injectable()
export class WindupHttpService extends Http {

    private configureRequest(method: RequestMethod, f: Function, url: string | Request, options: RequestOptionsArgs = {}, body?: any): Observable<Response> {
        let responseObservable: Observable<Response> = ...

    ...

    console.log("Load STARTED");
    if (this._eventBus)
        console.log("Load STARTED, firing");
    this._eventBus.fireEvent(new LoadingSomethingStartedEvent(responseObservable));

    return responseObservable2;
}
```

For the complete code, search github.com for project Windup.